# Broken Animation

Tags: css, animation

Where on earth have I gone wrong with this [css](/questions/tagged/css) animation?

```css
@keyframes home {
    0%   {left:0%;}
    50%  {left:100%;}
    100% {left:0%;}
}

#circle {
    animation: home 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<section id="circle"></section>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/thx3bb1p/)

Comment: `left` `right` `bottom` `top` properties work only if you give `position` css property other than `static` value. So apply `position: absolute` or `position: relative` or `position: fixed` (whatever suits you)

Comment: *Groan* Thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct, if you like.

Comment: Roko C. Buljan, already did. please check.

Answer (score 5):

Add `position:relative;` to your CSS in order to control the `top, right, bottom, left` properties

```css
#circle {
  position:relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: home 5s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes home {
    0%   {left:0px;}
    50%  {left:400px;}
    100% {left:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```